# Site stuck loading after using findOne() and updateOne()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

My website is hanging after clicking a "like" button. My mongo db is updating fine, and if I redirect the site to load a new page after clicking, it's fine. Is there a way to do this without reloading the page?

JS

```
app.post("/", async function(req) {

    console.log("/ works as post route");
    const requestedPostID = Object.keys(req.body)
    console.log(Object.keys(req.body));

    // Load the document
  const doc = await Post.findOne({ _id: requestedPostID });

  const update = { likeCount: 5 };
  await doc.updateOne(update);

  const updatedDoc = await Post.findOne({ likeCount: 5 });
  updatedDoc.likeCount; 

});
```

HTML

```
<form class="" action="/" method="post">
    <div class="field is-grouped">
  <button type="submit" name="<%=post._id%>" class="card-footer-item"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
  <button type="submit" name="dislikeButton" class="card-footer-item"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your logic completely, but I see couple of problems with your Mongo code

1. `const requestedPostID = Object.keys(req.body)` This returns array of keys but not the `requestedPostID` so you are querying with a wrong `_id`
2. Following code is wrong, `updateOne` takes filter and update

   const update = { likeCount: 5 };

   await doc.updateOne(update);
3. Where is the `res.send()`? That's probably the reason why your UI is stuck